# Vlookup in Pandas with approximate match

Tags: pandas

I need to do a vlookup style operation on two pandas dataframes

The Vlookup function in Excel has an extra parameter whether it should find an approximate or exact match. For exact match I know I can using the join function. But how would I do the approximate match where I find the next larger value?

For instance, if I have a marks and grades definition dataframe, like this:

```
Student Mark
John    65
Peter   75
Jason   79
```

And

```
Mark    Symbol
50      D
60      C  # table indicates a mark between 60 and 69 is a C symbol
70      B
80      A
```

How can I get a table like this:

```
Student Mark    Symbol
John    65      C
Peter   75      B
Jason   79      B
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) for merge on nearest key

```
In [2484]: pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='Mark')
Out[2484]:
  Student  Mark Symbol
0    John    65      C
1   Peter    75      B
2   Jason    79      B
```

---

Details

```
In [2485]: df1
Out[2485]:
  Student  Mark
0    John    65
1   Peter    75
2   Jason    79

In [2486]: df2
Out[2486]:
   Mark Symbol
0    50      D
1    60      C
2    70      B
3    80      A
```

Comment: Excellent, didn't know about that function!

Comment: note that default is `direction='backward'` not `'nearest'` as the explanation in the answer suggests (but the results are as requested by the OP, I'm just noting the inconsistency between code & explanation for clarity)

Comment: @IanS I tried to after he gave it, but it said I have to wait 10 minutes before I can accept... Accepted now

Comment: Only works if _both_ data frames are sorted on the key. In typical spreadsheet usage of VLOOKUP only the look-up table ("df2" here) need be sorted.