# problem with using merge_asof from Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have these two dataframes:

DF1=

```
 Inflow
0  9810998109
1  5591255912
2  7394273942
3  7866678666
4  1820118202
5  9812198109
6  9810998101
7  4304043040
8  9810998121
```

DF2=

```
       Inflow  mi_to_zcta5
0  3371433756    11.469054
1  1790118201    24.882142
```

I'd like to do an operation where I can merge these two dataframes based in the 'Inflow' column. Sort of like trying to recreate a VLookUp Excel function with approximate matching (like its shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357897/vlookup-in-pandas-with-approximate-match)). But I get a failure each time. The line I've been trying to use for this purpose is this one:

```
test = pd.merge_asof(DF1, DF2, on = 'mi_to_zcta5')
```

I've tried using the additional settings like 'allow_exact_matches' set to 'False' but I've not succeeded.

This is the error I get:

```
 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5280)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5126)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1210, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20523)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20477)
KeyError: 'mi_to_zcta5'
```

I'd like to get a dataframe with 10 rows, with the "Inflow" column and an additional column of 'mi_to_zcta5' with the correspondant nearest value (if that's possible). Just like one would do in VLookUp in excel using approximate match.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: df1 do not have mi_to_zcta5

Comment: @eyllanesc  So I should change the key for 'Inflow' instead?

Comment: @AquilesPáez I do not know, I just edit the question, I think you should ask `@Wen`

Comment: Yes, you can only merge on keys which exist in both DataFrames, so `Inflow` in this case.

Comment: @AquilesPáez, please check the answer if it helps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your solution:

In your first dataFrame(df1) you have only column while Second(df2) has two, while doing `pd.merge` you have to choose `outer`, which is a union of the keys. This means all of the indexes are shown and where it has missing cols it keeps them as NaN.

```
>>> df1
       Inflow
0  9810998109
1  5591255912
2  7394273942
3  7866678666
4  1820118202
5  9812198109
6  9810998101
7  4304043040
8  9810998121
>>> df2
       Inflow  mi_to_zcta5
0  3371433756    11.469054
1  1790118201    24.882142
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> pd.merge( df1, df2, on=['Inflow'], how='outer')
        Inflow  mi_to_zcta5
0   9810998109          NaN
1   5591255912          NaN
2   7394273942          NaN
3   7866678666          NaN
4   1820118202          NaN
5   9812198109          NaN
6   9810998101          NaN
7   4304043040          NaN
8   9810998121          NaN
9   3371433756    11.469054
10  1790118201    24.882142
```

Note: you can not merge on the Key `'mi_to_zcta5` as this is not present on `df`

Comment: Thanks so much @pygo. BTW, what if I wanted to make all my 10 rows choose the closest value between 11.469054 and 24.882142? Is there a way to make something like that possible?

Comment: @AquilesPáez, Glad it helped,  are exactly you needed.