# Pandas merge_asof() producing «'NoneType' object is not callable» error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

this is a continuation from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732174/problem-with-using-merge-asof-from-pandas) (that already provides a good outcome, but yet not exactly what I fully need).

I have these two dataframes:

DF1=

```
       Inflow
0  9810998109
1  5591255912
2  7394273942
3  7866678666
4  1820118202
5  9812198109
6  9810998101
7  4304043040
8  9810998121
Inflow    object
dtype: object
```

DF2=

```
       Inflow  mi_to_zcta5
0  3371433756    11.469054
1  1790118201    24.882142
Inflow         object
mi_to_zcta5    object
dtype: object
```

The outcome I would like is the following (in this case assuming all the inflow values from DF1['Inflow'] have as closest match the row [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732174/problem-with-using-merge-asof-from-pandas) from DF2['Inflow']:

```
           Inflow    mi_to_zcta5
    0  9810998109    24.88214228
    1  5591255912    24.88214228
    2  7394273942    24.88214228
    3  7866678666    24.88214228
    4  1820118202    24.88214228
    5  9812198109    24.88214228
    6  9810998101    24.88214228
    7  4304043040    24.88214228
    8  9810998121    24.88214228
    Inflow    object
    dtype: object
```

I would like that every DF1['Inflow'] element could find the nearest similar key on DF2['Inflow'], and once that condition is met, then get the value from DF2['mi_to_zcta5']. I tried different settings on Pandas, but all of them returned the same error:

> 'NoneType' object is not callable

I tried this (please note that Inflow columns are bot set to object because that's the dtype a column gets when is set as a string, and it has to be like that because I may have other keys with a mixture of numbers and letters):

```
test = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on = 'Inflow')
test = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on = 'Inflow', allow_exact_matches=False)
test = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on = 'Inflow', direction= 'nearest', allow_exact_matches=False)
```

Unfortunately, none succeeded, is this something achievable? I'd love to know.

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

Comment: `I may have other keys with a mixture of numbers and letters`. Well that's your issue. How do you define the absolute distance between '`awwe12312'` and `7`, because `pandas` doesn't know how to

Comment: @ALollz what I want to achieve is the outcome VLookUp would have on an Excel sheet when I set the last parameter to "True", indicating I want the closest match to the key I'm searching for. I've seen other posts using a similar approach but I can't make it work for me unfortunately.

Comment: But I don't think you can. I can make it work with your subset of data, because it's totally numeric. But on your actual data it's guaranteed to fail because the documention for the `on` keyword specifies: `Field name to join on. Must be found in both DataFrames. The data MUST be ordered. Furthermore this MUST BE A NUMERIC COLUMN, such as datetimelike, integer, or float.`

Comment: If you want a solution to your problem, I suggest you include a [mcve] that encompasses your entire problem (a column with both integers and strings) and the expected output where you match a string with something else, explaining how you calculate the distance in those cases. Is it edit distance? Is it absolute distance for things that can be cast to numeric? What happens when you compare a numeric value and a string?

Comment: @ALollz I was going to do that until I found this on GitHub (which solves my issue as I want it): https://github.com/RobinFiveWords/merge_closest